# Modifing Desire2Learn Groups using the Valance REST API

Tags: desire2learn, valence

I'm a bit confused on how we are supposed to update a group using the Valence API.

According to documentation, **"Name,Code & Description"** are required for updating, but the FETCH group block only returns **"GroupID,Name, Description and Enrollments"**. If Group Code is not returned in the fetch, what value are we supposed to use in the update block if we only want to update the name?  Since description is provided I can just feed that back, but what am I supposed to do about code ... just lose that data?

Perhaps there a way to send an update that will update only specific fields in the update block? When I omit fields from the update block I currently receive an error (ie in the case I only want to update the name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Code` property for Groups is intended to be the "org-defined code" for the group (for a course offering, this is often called the "course code"), the one that might appear in the organization's SIS system, for example.

Because groups in Desire2Learn's Learning Suite are considered "org units", when you create one, you need to provide it with an appropriate org-defined code (`Code`) -- if your organization doesn't use org-defined codes for groups, then you can decide to systematically use some other kind of data by convention (a name, a descriptive string, and so on). You are correct that's inconvenient for the *Fetch* form of the GroupData structure not to provide this value for you, but the value will be accessible to callers through the organization structure routes (because the newly created group is just an special kind of org unit).

In Learning Suite v10.2 (LP API v1.3+) and later, you can use [a single GET call to fetch back the properties for an org unit](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/orgunit.html#get--d2l-api-lp-%28version%29-orgstructure-%28orgUnitId%29). In versions prior to v10.2, you will need to fetch the list of parents for the group to get a parent org unit ID, or if you already know the org unit ID for the course offering that owns the group you can use that; *then* you use that org unit ID to fetch its list of children: your group will be in that list. The `OrgUnit` and `OrgUnitProperties` structures both contain the `Code` property that you need here.

Comment: Thanks for this Viktor, I was able to retrieve the code using  organization structure routes, but it looks like I still need to fetch the `GroupData` block since neither the `OrgUnit` or `OrgUnityProperties` block contains the description needed for the update of `GroupData`.

Since groups are considered org units I thought it could just update the group info using org structure routes, but ran into the same issue. Fetch returns an `OrgUnit` block _(Identifier,Name,Code,Type)_ but update requires an `OrgUnitProperties` block _(Identifier,Name,Code,**Path**,Type)_

Comment: Yes, you're correct; the lack of these properties on the fetch calls that would be required for an update are inelegant enough that their absence is arguably a defect... I'd encourage you to contact D2L support about these issues.